# flutter connect FTP and download file

Tags: flutter, dart, ftp

I am trying to connect to FTP with `ftpconnect 1.0.0` and download a file.
There was something I didn't understand, so I wrote a question.
If you look at the method that connects to FTP and downloads a file, it takes two parameters.

```
/// Download the Remote File [sRemoteName] to the local File [fFile]
Future<bool> downloadFile(
    String? sRemoteName,
    File fFile, {
    TransferMode mode = TransferMode.binary,
    FileProgress? onProgress,
    bool? supportIPv6,
  }) {
    return FileDownload(_socket, mode, _log).downloadFile(sRemoteName, fFile,
        onProgress: onProgress, supportIPV6: supportIPv6);
  }
```

Is `sRemoteName` the name of the file on FTP and `fFile` the file you want to save?
If it is correct, how do I set the path to save it in the app?
Thanks in advance for the reply.

my source code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:ftpconnect/ftpconnect.dart';

class FTPServer extends ChangeNotifier{
  FTPConnect? ftpConnect;
  File? file;

  Future<void> _fileMock(String strFileName) async {
    final Directory directory = Directory('/test')
      ..createSync(recursive: true);
    file = File('${directory.path}/$strFileName');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //FTP Connection
  connectionFTP() async {
    ftpConnect = FTPConnect('IP address', user: 'user', pass: 'password', port: portNumber);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //Change Dir
  Future<void> changeDirectoryFTP(String strFilePath) async {
    try {
      bool bRes = await ftpConnect!.connect();
      await ftpConnect!.changeDirectory(strFilePath);
    }catch(e){
      print('Error : ${e.toString()}');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //Download File
  Future<void> downloadFileFTP() async{
    try {
      bool bRes = await ftpConnect!.connect();
      await ftpConnect!.downloadFileWithRetry('FTP File Name', File name to save , pRetryCount: 1);
      await ftpConnect!.disconnect();
    }catch(e){
      print('Error : ${e.toString()}');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
I saved the file to the appropriate path using `path_provider`. Below is the modified source.

```
  Future<void> _fileMock(String strFileName) async {
    final Directory appDocDir  = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    file = File('$appDocPath/$strFileName');
    print('appDocPath : $appDocPath');
    print('file : $file');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //connect FTP
  connectionFTP() async {
    ftpConnect = FTPConnect('ip addr', user: 'user', pass: 'pass', port: port);
    notifyListeners();
  }

//download file
  Future<void> downloadFileFTP() async{
    try {
      bool bRes = await ftpConnect!.connect();
      _fileMock('filename');
      await ftpConnect!.downloadFileWithRetry('ftp_filename', file!, pRetryCount: 1);
      print('path2 : ${file!.path}');
      await ftpConnect!.disconnect();

      print('file Name : ${file!}');
    }catch(e){
      print('Error : ${e.toString()}');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution plz look into on below code it will work both passive and Active mode, i hope enjoy the code.

```
try{
   bool iscomplete = false;
   FTPConnect ftpConnect = FTPConnect(
    "example.com",
    user: "ftppwd",
    pass: "ftpusername",
    securityType: SecurityType.FTP,
    debug: true,
  );
   await ftpConnect.connect();
   String fileName =
      'ftpseverfilepath/imagetest.jpg';//set server file path to download
  Directory generalDownloadDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');//set save download file path to local storage directory

  final file =
      File('${(await generalDownloadDir).path}/imagetest.jpg');
   ftpConnect.supportIPV6 = true;//set false passive and true active mode
   iscomplete = await ftpConnect.downloadFile(fileName, file,
      onProgress: (progressInPercent, totalReceived, fileSize) {
    setState(() {
      percent = progressInPercent;//get download percent data type double
      _received = totalReceived;//get download received data type int
      _total = fileSize;//get download total data type int
     
    });
  });
  ftpConnect.transferType = TransferType.binary;//set data transferred type binary or ASCII or auto
  ftpConnect.disconnect();
  setState(() {
    iscomplete = true;
  });
  print("resp==$iscomplete");//print the response data
} catch (e) {
  //error
  setState(() {
    iscomplete = false;//print the error msg
  });
}
```